# Limiting Select options for non admin users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, filter

I have an options select drop-down that currently selects all "Categories" from a database of questions. ie, there are 100 questions, and 5 categories, so each category has 20 questions.

If the current user isn't an admin, they're assigned a category.

How do I limit the select to only their assigned category questions?

I figure I can do this easily from the view, but wouldn't it be better to do from the controller/model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is most definitely something that is much better suited to the controller / model level. Doing security on the front-end is a big no-no in my book. You want something like this:

Controller:

```
@categories = Category.editable_by(current_user)
```

Model

```
def self.editable_by(user)
  user.admin? ? all : scoped_to(user)
end

private

def scoped_to(user)
  where(category_id: user.category_id)
end
```

Not sure what your schema is looking like... but something in that ballpark should do it.

EDIT: Not sure in this context, but scoped_to may need to be def self.scoped_to. I forget how it works with private scopes.

Comment: Thank you.  Since I'm a Rails noob, can you give me a good resource/more info on scoping? I don't get it.

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes Anytime you call Category.where(name: 'Foobar') you are getting back categories scoped to those conditions. What's cool about scopes is they are presented so they can be chained. scope :visible -> { where(visible: true) }. You can then called Category.visible.where(name: 'Foobar')